# C defining functions?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand why this program prints out 8.

```
#define mul(x,y) (x * y)
int main() {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 4;
    int z = 0;
    z = mul(x+1, y+1);
    printf(“4*5 = %d \n”, z);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace#Function-like_macros) aren't functions**

After the first phase of compilation, preprocessing, the macro **is expanded**:

```
z = mul(x+1, y+1);
// becomes
z = (x+1 * y+1);
```

No doubt that `x + 1*y + 1 == 8`.

A better way to define this macro is to **parenthesize `x` and `y`**:

```
#define mul(x, y) ((x)*(y))
```

You can try it yourself: Compile this code with `gcc -E foo.c -o foo.i`

```
#define mul(x, y) (x * y)
int x = 3;
int y = 4;
int z = mul(x+1, y+1)
```

And see the content of `foo.i`.

Comment: So this can be seen as order of operations?

Comment: @rubberduck Yes.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks... I was sleepy typing this answer...

Answer (score 0):

[A macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function-like-Macros.html#Function-like-Macros) doesn't perform a mathematical operation but code replacement.

So after preprocessing step, your code should look like this:

```
 int main() {
     int x = 3;
     int y = 4;
     int z = 0;
     z = (x+1 * y+1);
     printf(“4*5 = %d \n”, z);
  }
```

So z should be equal to `3 + 4 * 1 + 1`, that is 8.

Comment: It's "roughly" 8?

Comment: @KeithThompson Misunderstanding about the word's meaning from a non-native English speaker. I apologize, I corrected. Thank you for bringing this to my attention!

Comment: @vmonteco I'm not a native English speaker, either. But I can assure you that "roughly" means "approximately", which is not a good word when you want to mean "actually" or "finally".

Comment: @iBug Yes, that's precisely what you could call a misunderstanding I think. It can happen.

Comment: @vmonteco: You do much better in your second(?) language than I do in mine.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you! But sadly sometimes I still make mistakes. My bad again!

Comment: @vmonteco: Please don't worry about it. One apology was more than sufficient.